# Is there a way to open javascript functions in new tabs?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, javascript, browser-tabs

So, I'm trying to use a website that allows searching, and is pretty slow.  Naturally, I'd like to open all of the interesting results in tabs, so I don't have to wait for them all to load.

Unfortunately, the developer of the site decided that rather than normal links they'd use javascript.  So when I control-click on the results pages, loading them doesn't work properly.

It seems like it might be possible to have a firefox extension that clones the page and executes the javascript on the clone in a new tab.  Does something like that exist?

In case it's helpful, the page I'm trying to use is http://www.loopnet.com

Comment: Gotta love accessibility gone horribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/1303) promises to do that.  I have not tried it and have no idea if it will work for you (based on comments on the script it appears that it doesn't work in at least some situations).

Another (probably better) option is the [smart middle click](http://dmextension.mozdev.org/misc.html) addon for firefox.

Comment: That was much more than I could find, but unfortunately I wasn't able to get either the greasemonkey script or the smart middle click addon working.

The greasemonkey script seemed to do nothing.
The smart middle click looks like it only works up to firefox 1.5.. :\